# How to add a conditional statement in a c# windows form with a ms access database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, winforms, ms-access-2010

I am using c# windows forms application connected to a Microsoft access database. I want the txtOrderMore text box to either show "yes" if txtSupplyLeft is less than 5 and "no" if txtSupplyLeft is greater than 5. I wanted this condition to happen once I inserted a new record into the database. This is what I came up with

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Products (ProductName, ProductPrice, Quantity, [Weight(g)], DaysSupplyLeft) values ('"+txtProductName.Text+"', "+txtProductPrice.Text+ ", " + txtQuantity.Text + ", " + txtWeight.Text + ", " + txtSupplyLeft.Text + ")";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            txtProductName.Text = "";
            txtProductPrice.Text = "";
            txtQuantity.Text = "";
            txtWeight.Text = "";
            txtSupplyLeft.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Products ([OrderMore?]) values ('Yes') where "+txtSupplyLeft.Text+"<5";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            txtOrderMore.Text = "Yes";
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Products ([OrderMore?]) values ('No') where "+txtSupplyLeft.Text+"";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            txtOrderMore.Text = "No";
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
    }
```

But whenever I run this code, the condition that outputs "yes" doesn't work, a.k.a I never get a yes when I input a value lower than 5. It does output no, but whenever I save a new record I get connection exceptions, it tells me the connection hasn't been closed when I clearly added "connection.Close()" at the end of each try loops.
I am very new to windows forms and SQL queries therefore I am not really sure where I could have gone wrong.
I have seen many comments before recommending parameterized queries but I'm not too sure how to do that.

Comment: Also when I run it, it keeps throwing errors like "Missing ;" when there clearly isn't anything missing as I checked, and I don't get any errors when I'm coding.

Comment: There are many problems with your code... 1. INSERT Queries are not correct... 2. You have multiple INSERT queries executed and the the last block has `txtOrderMore.Text = "No";` so it will be always `No`. 3. Your code have poor exception handling. 4. It is not clear what you are trying to do in this code. 5. You are not using parameterized queries, leaving open for SQL Injection.

Comment: An INSERT statement inserts *new* records. I assume you want UPDATE to alter existing ones

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I want to do both, because when I insert a new record I want the txtOrderMore  text box (and field in the database) to change automatically

Comment: @JohnG I meant "missing ;" as in missing semicolon, and it points to the line command.ExecuteNonQuery(); in the second try loop

Comment: Debug tip: what is *really* in that CommandText?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya would you mind to explain how can I fix the multiple insert queries for the code to work? And how should I handle the exceptions? I've also edited the question so it makes more sense hopefully. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I'm not sure what you mean, but I hoped it would be the query I wrote next to it

Comment: Inspect that actual query, I'm fairly certain it is not exactly what you hope it to be. Try and execute that actual query. For instance, I assume you want a column name, not a value

Comment: You should have decided the value of `OrderMore` by checking the value of `txtSupplyLeft.Text` in the first try block and inserted it to the `Products` table along with other values. You don't need the other two try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using parameters with OleDbCommand, it's important to know the following:

[OleDbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
> parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
> OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
> question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
> OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
> the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Below, I'll show how to insert data to an Access database, as well as, how to update data in an access database. I'll be using `OleDbParameter` throughout the code.

**Access database name**: Database1.accdb

In **Access (Design View)**,

**Table Name**: Product

- **ID**: AutoNumber
- **ProductName**: Short Text (General tab => Field Size: 50)
- **Price**: Currency (General tab => Format: Currency)
- **Quantity**: Number
- **Weight(g)**: Number
- **DaysSupplyLeft**: Number
- **ReorderWhenQuantityReaches**: Number
- **OrderMore**: Yes/No (General tab => Format: Yes/No)

If creating the table **programmatically**, use the following column definitions:

**Table Name**: Product

- **ID**: AutoIncrement not null Primary Key
- **ProductName**: varchar(50) not null
- **Price**: currency
- **Quantity**: integer
- **Weight(g)**: integer
- **DaysSupplyLeft**: integer
- **ReorderWhenQuantityReaches**: integer
- **OrderMore**: bit

**Note**: After the table is created programmatically, to make it look as desired in Access, it may be necessary to change the "Format" property for some of the Fields (Columns). Open the database in Access. Right-click "Product". Select "Design View". Then set the properties as described above in "In Access (Design View)".

In your VS project, ensure that your project has a reference for `System.Data`.

**VS 2019**:

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Click **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Data**

Create a class named **HelperAccess**

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class...** (name: HelperAccess.cs)

Add the following using statement to HelperAccess.cs:

`using System.Data.OleDb;`

In "HelperAccess.cs" add the following variables:

```
private string _databaseFilename = string.Empty;
private string _connectionString = string.Empty;
```

Then add the following constructor:

```
public HelperAccess(string databaseFilename)
{
    _databaseFilename = databaseFilename;
    _connectionString = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Persist Security Info=False;", _databaseFilename);
}
```

In "HelperAccess.cs", create a method named **AddProduct**, add a variable to return, and add the return statement

```
public int AddProduct(string productName, decimal price, int quantity, double weightInGrams, int daysSupplyLeft, int reorderWhenQuantityReaches, bool orderMore = false)
{
    int result = 0;

    return result;
}
```

We'll start by creating the SQL, so we know what parameters need to specified.

```
string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Price, Quantity, [Weight(g)], DaysSupplyLeft, ReorderWhenQuantityReaches, OrderMore) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Next, we'll create an instance of `OleDbConnection` and open the connection. When a `using` statement is used, it ensures that the object is closed and/or disposed when execution goes out of scope.

```
public int AddProduct(string productName, decimal price, int quantity, double weightInGrams, int daysSupplyLeft, int reorderWhenQuantityReaches, bool orderMore = false)
{
    int result = 0;
    string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Price, Quantity, [Weight(g)], DaysSupplyLeft, ReorderWhenQuantityReaches, OrderMore) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, we'll create an instance of `OleDbCommand` inside the instance of `OleDbConnection`.

```
public int AddProduct(string productName, decimal price, int quantity, double weightInGrams, int daysSupplyLeft, int reorderWhenQuantityReaches, bool orderMore = false)
{
    int result = 0;
    string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Price, Quantity, [Weight(g)], DaysSupplyLeft, ReorderWhenQuantityReaches, OrderMore) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
        {
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Let's look at how to declare a parameter. First, create a new instance of `OleDbParameter`.

```
OleDbParameter paramProductName = new OleDbParameter();
```

Now, set the properties. It's important to set the correct data types for the database columns. While "ParameterName" isn't used by OleDbCommand, I've chosen to set the property because it makes debugging easier. If the value isn't set the value will show as "Parameter1", "Parameter2", etc...

According to [Set the field size](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-the-field-size-ba65e5a7-2e6f-4737-8e72-36b93f966a33) (Access),

- Long Integer — For integers that range from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647. Storage requirement is four bytes.

[Data types for Access desktop databases](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-types-for-access-desktop-databases-df2b83ba-cef6-436d-b679-3418f622e482#ID0EAABAAA=Newer_versions)

- **Currency**: Monetary data, stored with 4 decimal places of precision. 8
  bytes
- **Yes/No**: Boolean (true/false) data; Access stores the numeric
  value zero (0) for false, and -1 for true. 1 byte.

and according to [Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

- **int** -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647  Signed 32-bit integer   System.Int32

We also need to look at [OleDbType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype?view=netframework-4.8)

- **BigInt**: A 64-bit signed integer (DBTYPE_I8). This maps to Int64.
- **Boolean**: A Boolean value
- **Currency**: A currency value...
- **Decimal**:
- **Double**: A floating-point number...
- **Integer**: A 32-bit signed integer (DBTYPE_I4). This maps to Int32.

  OleDbParameter paramProductName = new OleDbParameter();
  paramProductName.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
  paramProductName.ParameterName = "@productName";
  paramProductName.Value = productName;

To add the property to our instance of OleDbCommand (sqlCmd), we do the following:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramProductName);
```

Here's what we have so far:

```
public int AddProduct(string productName, decimal price, int quantity, double weightInGrams, int daysSupplyLeft, int reorderWhenQuantityReaches, bool orderMore = false)
{
    int result = 0;
    string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Price, Quantity, [Weight(g)], DaysSupplyLeft, ReorderWhenQuantityReaches, OrderMore) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
        {
            OleDbParameter paramProductName = new OleDbParameter();
            paramProductName.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
            paramProductName.ParameterName = "@productName";
            paramProductName.Value = productName;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramProductName);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, we can add the rest of the parameters, keeping in mind that they must be added in the order that they are used (referenced). Before we do, let's look at how to execute the SQL.

To execute the SQL:

```
result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**AddProduct**:

```
public int AddProduct(string productName, decimal price, int quantity, double weightInGrams, int daysSupplyLeft, int reorderWhenQuantityReaches, bool orderMore = false)
{
    int result = 0;
    string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, Price, Quantity, [Weight(g)], DaysSupplyLeft, ReorderWhenQuantityReaches, OrderMore) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
        {

            //ProductName
            OleDbParameter paramProductName = new OleDbParameter();
            paramProductName.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
            paramProductName.ParameterName = "@productName";
            paramProductName.Value = productName;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramProductName);

            //Price
            OleDbParameter paramPrice = new OleDbParameter();
            paramPrice.OleDbType = OleDbType.Currency;
            paramPrice.ParameterName = "@price";
            paramPrice.Value = price;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramPrice);

            //Quantity
            OleDbParameter paramQuantity = new OleDbParameter();
            paramQuantity.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramQuantity.ParameterName = "@quantity";
            paramQuantity.Value = quantity;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramQuantity);

            //Weight(g)
            OleDbParameter paramWeight = new OleDbParameter();
            paramWeight.OleDbType = OleDbType.Double;
            paramWeight.ParameterName = "@weight";
            paramWeight.Value = weightInGrams;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramWeight);

            //DaysSupplyLeft
            OleDbParameter paramDaysSupplyLeft = new OleDbParameter();
            paramDaysSupplyLeft.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramDaysSupplyLeft.ParameterName = "@daysSupplyLeft";
            paramDaysSupplyLeft.Value = daysSupplyLeft;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramDaysSupplyLeft);

            //ReorderWhenSupplyReaches
            OleDbParameter paramReorderWhenQuantityReaches = new OleDbParameter();
            paramReorderWhenQuantityReaches.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramReorderWhenQuantityReaches.ParameterName = "@reorderWhenQuantityReaches";
            paramReorderWhenQuantityReaches.Value = reorderWhenQuantityReaches;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramReorderWhenQuantityReaches);

            //orderMore
            OleDbParameter paramOrderMore = new OleDbParameter();
            paramOrderMore.OleDbType = OleDbType.Boolean;
            paramOrderMore.ParameterName = "@orderMore";
            paramOrderMore.Value = orderMore;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramOrderMore);

            //execute command
            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now let's look at how to perform an update to the database table. Create a method named **UpdateProductQuantity** in "HelperAccess.cs"

```
public int UpdateProductQuantity(int id, int quantity)
{

}
```

Create the SQL:

```
string sqlText = "UPDATE Product SET Quantity = ? WHERE ID = ?";
```

The rest of the code is similar to the previous method, so I won't go over it again.

**UpdateProductQuantity**:

```
public int UpdateProductQuantity(int id, int quantity)
{
    string sqlText = "UPDATE Product SET Quantity = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    int result = 0;

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
        {
            //Note: Parameters MUST be added in the order that they are used (referenced) since
            //ParameterName isn't used by OleDbCommand. However, setting the
            //ParameterName property can be useful for debugging 

            // Quantity
            OleDbParameter paramQuantity = new OleDbParameter();
            paramQuantity.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramQuantity.ParameterName = "@quantity";

            //calculate quantity remaining and set value
            paramQuantity.Value = quantity;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramQuantity);

            //ID
            OleDbParameter paramId = new OleDbParameter();
            paramId.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
            paramId.Value = id;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

            //execute command
            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

How might we be able to use the code to update the quantity? If a customer makes a purchase, we'll want to update the quantity. One can get the current quantity, subtract the quantity purchased, and update the database. Then if the quantity falls below the quantity specified in "ReorderWhenQuantityReaches" in the Product table, we'll set the value of "OrderMore" to "Yes" and raise an event that subscribers can listen for. This can be used to update the OrderMore TextBox on the form.

Let's create a method to get the existing quantity from the Product table. Since this is  part of the update process, we can open the connection once and then use that connection in our method that gets the quantity.

In "HelperAccess.cs", create a method named **GetCurrentQuantity**, add a variable to return, and add the return statement.

```
public int GetCurrentQuantity(OleDbConnection con, int id)
{
    int currentQuantity = 0;

    return currentQuantity;
}
```

Create the SQL query:

```
string sqlText = "SELECT quantity from Product where ID = ?";
```

Create an instance of OleDbCommand, and add the id parameter:

```
public int GetCurrentQuantity(OleDbConnection con, int id)
{
    int currentQuantity = 0;
    string sqlText = "SELECT quantity from Product where ID = ?";
    
    using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
    {

        //ID
        OleDbParameter paramId = new OleDbParameter();
        paramId.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
        paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
        paramId.Value = id;

        //add parameter
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

    }

    return currentQuantity;
}
```

There are a number of ways to read a value from the database. We'll use OleDbDataReader. Create a new instance of OleDbReader and use it to get the value. The column can be either referenced by it's column name or relative position within the query. The index is zero based. Since we only specify one column, the index is zero.

**GetCurrentQuantity**:

```
public int GetCurrentQuantity(OleDbConnection con, int id)
{
    int currentQuantity = 0;
    string sqlText = "SELECT quantity from Product where ID = ?";
    
    using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
    {

        //ID
        OleDbParameter paramId = new OleDbParameter();
        paramId.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
        paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
        paramId.Value = id;

        //add parameter
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);


        //get value
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                currentQuantity = (int)reader[0];
            }
        }
    }

    return currentQuantity;
}
```

Next, let's create a method that updates the value of "OrderMore" when the quantity changes. We'll get the current value of quantity. We also need to know what quantity "triggers" the value of "OrderMore" to be changed. This value is stored in "ReorderWhenQuantityReaches" so we'll need to retrieve that value and compare it to quantity. Once we complete our comparision, we can raise the event (OrderMoreValueUpdated) to notify subscribers whether the value of "OrderMore" is "Yes" or "No".

Before we continue, since we'll be raising an event in our method, let's see how to create an event that can be subscribed to. I won't go into too much detail about events, as one can find numerous articles/posts about them. I'll just show the code that needs to be added to make it work. Add the following code towards the top of "HelperAccess.cs":

```
public class HelperAccess
{
    public delegate void EventHandlerOrderMoreValueUpdated(object sender, string e);
    
    //event that subscribers can subscribe to
    public event EventHandlerOrderMoreValueUpdated OrderMoreValueUpdated;

                           ...
}
```

Here's how to raise the event:

```
//check if event has subscribers
if (OrderMoreValueUpdated != null)
{
    //raise event
    OrderMoreValueUpdated(this, "test");
}
```

Now we're ready to create our method **UpdateOrderMore**. Since I've already covered the different parts of the code, I'll just show the completed method.

**UpdateOrderMore**

```
public int UpdateOrderMore(OleDbConnection con, int id)
{
    string sqlText = string.Empty;
    int reorderWhenQuantityReaches = 0;
    int result = 0;

    //get Quantity
    int currentQuantity = GetCurrentQuantity(con, id);

    //get ReorderWhenQuantityReaches
    sqlText = "SELECT ReorderWhenQuantityReaches from Product where ID = ?";
    using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
    {
        //ParameterName isn't used by OleDbCommand. However, setting the
        //ParameterName property can be useful for debugging 

        //ID
        OleDbParameter paramId = new OleDbParameter();
        paramId.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
        paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
        paramId.Value = id;

        //add parameter
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

        //get value
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                reorderWhenQuantityReaches = (int)reader[0];
            }
        }
    }

    sqlText = "UPDATE Product SET OrderMore = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
    {
        //Note: Parameters MUST be added in the order that they are used (referenced) since
        //ParameterName isn't used by OleDbCommand. However, setting the
        //ParameterName property can be useful for debugging 

        //if quantity is below value specified in ReorderWhenQuantityReaches, then 
        //set OrderMore to true (Yes)

        bool orderMoreVal = false;
        string orderMoreValStr = string.Empty;
        if (currentQuantity <= reorderWhenQuantityReaches)
        {
            orderMoreVal = true;
            orderMoreValStr = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            orderMoreVal = false;
            orderMoreValStr = "No";
        }

        //OrderMore
        OleDbParameter paramOrderMore = new OleDbParameter();
        paramOrderMore.OleDbType = OleDbType.Boolean;
        paramOrderMore.ParameterName = "@orderMore";
        paramOrderMore.Value = orderMoreVal;

        //add parameter
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramOrderMore);

        //ID
        OleDbParameter paramId = new OleDbParameter();
        paramId.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
        paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
        paramId.Value = id;

        //add parameter
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

        //execute command
        result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //check if event has subscribers
        if (OrderMoreValueUpdated != null)
        {
            //raise event
            OrderMoreValueUpdated(this, orderMoreValStr);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Finally, here's a method that incorporates the above code. As part of completing a sale, the current quantity needs to be reduced by the quantity that is being purchased. Then we'll check whether or not we need to order more of the product and report the result.

**UpdateProductQuantityAfterPurchase**

```
public int UpdateProductQuantityAfterPurchase(int id, int quantityPurchased)
{
    string sqlText = "UPDATE Product SET Quantity = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    int resultUpdateQuantity = 0;

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        //open connection
        con.Open();

        //get current quantity
        int currentQuantity = GetCurrentQuantity(con, id);

        using (OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, con))
        {
            //Note: Parameters MUST be added in the order that they are used (referenced) since
            //ParameterName isn't used by OleDbCommand. However, setting the
            //ParameterName property can be useful for debugging 

            // Quantity
            OleDbParameter paramQuantity = new OleDbParameter();
            paramQuantity.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramQuantity.ParameterName = "@quantity";

            //calculate quantity remaining and set value
            paramQuantity.Value = currentQuantity - quantityPurchased;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramQuantity);

            //ID
            OleDbParameter paramId = new OleDbParameter();
            paramId.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
            paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
            paramId.Value = id;

            //add parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

            //execute command
            resultUpdateQuantity = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (resultUpdateQuantity > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Info: " + resultUpdateQuantity + " row updated.");
            }
        }

        //update OrderMore
        int resultUpdateOrderMore = UpdateOrderMore(con, id);
    }

    return resultUpdateQuantity;
}
```

I can't add all of the code for the methods in "Helper.cs" because of the character limitation for a post, but the code is above. The layout of "Helper.cs" should look similar to the following ("..." is where the code goes):

**HelperAccess.cs**

```
public class HelperAccess
{

    private string _databaseFilename = string.Empty;
    private string _connectionString = string.Empty;

    public delegate void EventHandlerOrderMoreValueUpdated(object sender, string e);

    //event that subscribers can subscribe to
    public event EventHandlerOrderMoreValueUpdated OrderMoreValueUpdated;

    public HelperAccess(string databaseFilename)
    {
        _databaseFilename = databaseFilename;
        _connectionString = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Persist Security Info=False;", _databaseFilename);
    }

    public int AddProduct(string productName, decimal price, int quantity, double weightInGrams, int daysSupplyLeft, int reorderWhenQuantityReaches, bool orderMore = false)
    {
                           ...
    }

    public int GetCurrentQuantity(OleDbConnection con, int id)
    {
                           ...
    }

    public int UpdateProductQuantity(int id, int quantity)
    {
                           ...
    }

    public int UpdateProductQuantityAfterPurchase(int id, int quantityPurchased)
    {
                                   ...
    }

    public int UpdateOrderMore(OleDbConnection con, int id)
    {
                           ...
    }
}
```

**Usage**

For testing, I added the following to Form1:

The following **TextBox** controls were added to Form1:

- name: textBoxId
- name: textBoxProductName
- name: textBoxPrice
- name: textBoxQuantity
- name: textBoxWeight
- name: textBoxReorderWhenQuantityReaches
- name: textBoxDaysSupplyLeft
- name: textBoxOrderMore (ReadOnly: true)

**Note**: I also added a Label to the left of each TextBox.

Lastly, I added a Button (name: btnSave) to Form1.cs

[image]

**Form1.cs**:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static string _databaseFilename = @"C:\Users\Test\Documents\Database1.accdb";
    private HelperAccess _helperAccess = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create new instance
        _helperAccess = new HelperAccess(_databaseFilename);

        //subscribe to event
        _helperAccess.OrderMoreValueUpdated += _helperAccess_OrderMoreValueUpdated;
    }

    private void _helperAccess_OrderMoreValueUpdated(object sender, string e)
    {
        //needed for cross-threaded operations
        if (textBoxOrderMore.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBoxOrderMore.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate 
            { 
                textBoxOrderMore.Text = (string)e;
                textBoxOrderMore.Refresh();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxOrderMore.Text = (string)e;
            textBoxOrderMore.Refresh();
        }   
    }

    private void AddProduct()
    {
        //convert price
        decimal price = 0;
        Decimal.TryParse(textBoxPrice.Text, out price);

        //convert quantity
        int quantity = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(textBoxQuantity.Text, out quantity);

        //convert weight
        double weight = 0;
        Double.TryParse(textBoxWeight.Text, out weight);

        //convert days supply left
        int daysSupplyLeft = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(textBoxDaysSupplyLeft.Text, out daysSupplyLeft);

        //convert reorder when quantity reaches
        int reorderWhenQuantityReaches = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(textBoxReorderWhenQuantityReaches.Text, out reorderWhenQuantityReaches);


        //add product to database
        int result = _helperAccess.AddProduct(textBoxProductName.Text, price, quantity, weight, daysSupplyLeft, reorderWhenQuantityReaches);

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddProduct();
    }

}
```

To use UpdateProductQuantityAfterPurchase:

```
_helperAccess.UpdateProductQuantityAfterPurchase(id, 1);
```

Comment: wow. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question in this much detail! It actually helped me so much, i'm lost for words. Hope you have a great day!

Comment: Glad to hear the info was helpful. If this post resolved your issue, please consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: sorry one question, where you put the question marks, am I supposed to add the text boxes from the form? Because I've tried doing that and it doesn't work

Comment: The question marks are only in the SQL statement

Comment: In the code that I posted, all of the SQL code goes in "Helper.cs". I've updated the post to show the layout of "Helper.cs" -- directly above "Usage".  The Windows form code, is in "Form1.cs". I've added the text "Form1.cs" below "Usage" to make it more obvious where the "Form1.cs" code is.